# Optimizing global memory load in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

My task :
I have two matrices : A - (18 x 4194304) ; B - (18 x 1024).

I have to take each 18-length vector from A and compute distance with each 18-length vector from B and find minimum distance and index.

My code :

```
__device__
void GetMin(float &dist, int &idx)
{
    float dist2;
    int idx2;
    dist2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, dist, 16, 32);
    idx2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, idx, 16);
    if (dist > dist2)
    {
        dist = dist2;
        idx = idx2;
    }

    dist2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, dist, 8, 32);
    idx2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, idx, 8);
    if (dist > dist2)
    {
        dist = dist2;
        idx = idx2;
    }

    dist2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, dist, 4, 32);
    idx2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, idx, 4);
    if (dist > dist2)
    {
        dist = dist2;
        idx = idx2;
    }

    dist2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, dist, 2, 32);
    idx2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, idx, 2);
    if (dist > dist2)
    {
        dist = dist2;
        idx = idx2;
    }

    dist2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, dist, 1, 32);
    idx2 = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, idx, 1);
    if (dist > dist2)
    {
        dist = dist2;
        idx = idx2;
    }
}

__global__
void CalcMinDist_kernel(const float *A, const float *B, float *output, const int nNumPixels, int nNumImages)
{
    int tx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int lane_id = tx % 32;

    float dist = 0;
    int idx = 0;

    float fMin = 99999999;
    int nMinIdx = -1;

    for(int i = lane_id; i < 1024; i += 32)
    {
        dist = 0;
        for(int  j = 0; j < nNumImages; ++j)
        {
            int img_idx = blockIdx.x * ty + j * nNumPixels;
            dist += (A[img_idx] - B[i * nNumImages + j]) * 
                    (A[img_idx] - B[i * nNumImages + j]);
        }
        idx = i;
        GetMin(dist, idx);

        if(threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            if(fMin > dist)
            {
                fMin = dist;
                nMinIdx = idx;
            }
        }
    }

    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        output[blockIdx.x * ty] = nMinIdx;
    }
}
```

Looking at the profiler, I'm memory bound, and do have ~90% occupancy. Is there any way to speed up this operation?

Let me know if I need to provide any other information.

Comment: What is `GetMin`?

Comment: @talonmies I have added that function. It gets within warp argmin operation.

Comment: Start by marking all of your pointer parameters with  `__restrict`.

Comment: Also, your data structure access and variable naming are a bit confusing.

Comment: @einpoklum __restrict__ didn't help.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B: 1. See my answer. 2. You shouldn't remove it because it didn't provide a benefit. It is the semantically correct thing to say. A bit like `const`. Also, it might benefit a tweaked implementation.

Comment: @einpoklum Consider A as 18 images of size 2048 x 2048. 18 length vector is constructed by taking (i, j) value from 18 images. blockdimension - (32, 4, 1) & griddimension - (2048 * 2048 / 4, 1, 1)

Comment: The update of nMinIdx  and nMinIdx doesn't have to be done conditionally on thread ID. It is probably executed using predication but on the off chance it is caused branch divergence, you don't need it

Comment: @talonmies can you explain a bit more? Since all the threads in warp are executing the same code (a bit of divergence during if statement), it shouldn't impact the speed by a lot right? Also, I ran the code with GetMin(), it didn't affect the executing speed a lot. Global memory load is slow.

Comment: @talonmies I was wrong. I ran profiler and all the threads are divergent. Any tips on fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would look at the *algorithm* first. This is a geometric problem - treat it as such.

You should represent the B data using a different data structure, e.g. by clustering or building a partition structure (e.g. [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)). That will let you avoid actually computing the distance from most B elements. (You could also consider a project onto fewer dimensions, but the benefit of this may be more elusive.)

---

With respect to the access pattern - you would probably benefit from having consecutive threads working on consecutive elements of the 18-element-long vectors, rather than having threads work on complete 18-element-long vectors individually. That would better fit the memory layout - right now, a warp read is of many elements which are at distance 18 from each other. If I understand the code correctly anyway.

(I also think the `GetMin()` could avoid some of the index swaps, but that's not significant since you only perform very few of those.)

Comment: Let me think about this.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B: I'll just say I didn't think about A as 18 images of  dimensions 2ki x 2ki , but rather as a very large number of consecutive sequences of 18 elements each. I hope I haven't misunderstood.